# Не понимаю как сделать подключение множества аккаунтов для рассылки

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3, pyrogram

Не понимаю как сделать подключение множества аккаунтов для рассылки.

Работаю с sqlite3 все данные в отдельных колонках, hash, id, session код ниже

```
c = 0

a = 0

b = 1

api_hash = [api_hash for (api_hash,) in sql.execute("SELECT api_hash FROM Accounts")]
api_id = [api_id for (api_id,) in sql.execute("SELECT api_id FROM Accounts")]
api_sesions = [api_sesions for (api_sesions,) in sql.execute("SELECT session_string FROM Accounts")]


db.commit()


app = Client("alina", api_id=int(api_id[c]), api_hash=str(api_hash[c]), in_memory=True,
              session_string=str(api_sesions[c]))


def main():
    with app:
        while True:
          chat = [chatsid for (chatsid,) in sql.execute("SELECT chatsid FROM Accounts")]
          messages = [messages for (messages,) in sql.execute("SELECT message FROM Accounts")]
          timesras = [timesras for (timesras,) in sql.execute("SELECT secondsMsg FROM Accounts")]
          for i in chat:
            try:
              print(Fore.YELLOW, Style.BRIGHT, f'Задержка: {timesras[0]} секунд!\n' + Style.RESET_ALL)
              sleep(int(timesras[0]))
              app.send_message(chat_id=str(i), text=messages[0]) #МЕНЯТЬ ШАБЛОН ДЛЯ РАССЫЛКИ
              print(Fore.GREEN,Style.BRIGHT, f"✅Сообщение отправилось в этот чат {i}" + Style.RESET_ALL)
              print(Fore.CYAN,Style.BRIGHT, f'Отправленное сообщение: {str(messages[0])} \n\n' + Style.RESET_ALL)
            except Exception as e:
              
              print(Fore.RED,Style.BRIGHT,f"❌Сообщение не отправилось в этот чат {i}" + Style.RESET_ALL)
              print(e)


app.run(main())
```